# Overlapping text and `equation*`

Tags: equations, align, overlap

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{draftcopy}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[centerlast]{caption2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} \setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\newcommand{\toright}[1]{%
    \leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty13 
    \null\nobreak\hskip1em plus1fill\hbox{#1}%
}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\title{\vspace{-4cm}\textbf{Text}}
\author{Text}
\affil{\textbf{Mail me -}\;Text}
\affil{\textbf{Hello me -}\;Text}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
    \fancyhead[RE,LO]{Text}
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage} \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    
    \newpage    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Probability that more than 4 crews will be needed
    \begin{align*}
        &=\mbox{Probability that there are at least $5$ ships in the system}\\
        &=1-(P_0+P_1+P_2+P_3+P_4)\\
        &=1-\left[e^{-\rho}+\dfrac{\rho e^{-\rho}}{1!}+\dfrac{\rho^2 e^{-\rho}}{2!}+\dfrac{\rho^3 e^{-\rho}}{3!}+\dfrac{\rho^4 e^{-\rho}}{4!}\right]\quad\left[\because P_n=\dfrac{\rho^n e^{-\rho}}{n!}\right]\\
        &=1-e^{-\rho}\left[1+\dfrac{\rho }{1!}+\dfrac{\rho^2 }{2!}+\dfrac{\rho^3 }{3!}+\dfrac{\rho^4 }{4!}\right]\\
        &=1-e^{3/2}\left[1+\dfrac{{\left(3/2\right)} }{1!}+\dfrac{\left(3/2\right)^2 }{2!}+\dfrac{\left(3/2\right)^3 }{3!}+\dfrac{\left(3/2\right)^4 }{4!}\right]\\
        &=0.019
    \end{align*}
\item Problems arrive at a computer center in a Poisson fashion at an average rate of 5/day. The rules of the computer center are that any man waiting to get his problem solved must aid the man whose problem is currently being solved. If the time to solve a problem  with one man has an exponential distribution with mean time $1/3$ day and if the average solving time is inversely proportional to the number of people working on the problem, find the expected system time for a person entering the line.\\
\textbf{Solution:}\\
Here $\lambda=5$ problems/day and $\mu=3$ problems/day.\\
Sine the expected time in a system is given by $W_s=\dfrac{L_s}{\lambda}$, therefore first we find the expected number of persons working at any instant, i.e. $L_s$. Now
\begin{equation*}
L_s =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nP_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\dfrac{\rho^ne^{-\rho}}{n!}=\rho e^{-\rho}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\rho^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\rho e^{-\rho}\left[1+\dfrac{\rho}{1!}+\dfrac{\rho^2}{2!}
+\ldots\right]=\rho e^{-\rho}e^{\rho}=\rho=\dfrac{\lambda}{\mu}=\dfrac53 
\end{equation*}
Therefore $W_s=\dfrac{5/3}{5}$ day $=\dfrac13$ day $=8$ hours.
    \end{enumerate}

\subsection{Queuing Model-III: $(M/M/1):(N/FCFS)$}
This model is also based on the assumptions made for Model-I except a limit on the capacity of the system to accommodate only $N$ customers. Therefore in this model, when the queue length reaches to its maximum capacity $N$, no further arrival will be allowed to enter the system. Such a situation may arise in an emergency room in a hospital or at a barber shop with finite number of chairs for waiting customers etc.\\
ht
\end{document}
```

I am facing a problem of overlapping lines. Whenever I compile the codes in my main article, I find that the marked lines are getting overlapped.
[image: Error image]

To recheck, I compile only that segment creating a new file and there I find that no lines are overlapped.
[image: No error image]

In my original article, to get rid of this error, I have to put `\\` after every `\end{align}` or `\end{enumerate}` or `\end{equation}`. I searched thoroughly the article and find that the problem starts after the marked lines in the 1st image which means that there may be some problem in the `equation*` environment that I used for the marked equation. Before the marked line, wherever I used any environment, such overlapping did not occur.

I don't know whether its a complier problem or such is happening due to the lack of lineheight in a page margin. Any sort of help would be appreciated.

(I know when you compile this you won't get any overlapping lines as I did not get when I compiled it separately. That's why in support of my claim, I added the image of overlapping lines (1st image captured from my original article). Also I provided every preamble that I used to make this article)

Comment: Sorry, but the problem doesn't seem reproducible. You should however fix all the `fancyhdr` warnings and avoid loading packages you don't use; in particular `epsf` and `draftcopy`. Besides, `caption2` has been obsolete for several years.

Comment: your example produces `Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):` which you should fix, but produces no overlapping.  Please show the output _of the document you post_ not a different document. also do not load packages you do not use, it is very unlikely that you use `\usepackage{epsf}` for example. (unless your document was written before 1994)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the output is the 1st  image. 2nd image is produced by the same codes but complied in different tab

Comment: @egreg I deleted all those packages but still the problem exists

Comment: no, if you used the same code you would get the same output. post a small but complete example that produces overlapping.